Are alkyl groups electron withdrawing?
This recently published article claims that alkyl groups are infact electron withdrawing. Most introductory organic chemistry textbooks seem to contradict this observation. This question addresses a similar problem. Which source should I trust? The article states

In fact, there is already compelling evidence that alkyl groups exert an inductive electron-withdrawing effect (–I), accompanied by an electron-releasing hyperconjugation effect (+R). It would appear that the evidence for this position is not widely known and, as a result, textbook authors and educators routinely invoke alkyl group inductive electron-donating effects to explain phenomena that are best explained in other ways.

If the inductive effect of alkyl groups has no evidence behind it, why do textbooks still contain it? Is the inductive effect a real phenomenon, or is it just a tool we use to explain things?

It's just a tool and I wonder why they even bother digging into it. BTW it's as duplicate of many earlier questions about it, but maybe it could be used to dupe them instead, depending on possible answers

I found a similar question. I support marking the question as duplicate and closing it

I need to go rewrite my GOC notes...

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/128443/change-in-inductive-effect-of-a-susbstituent-when-r-group-replaces-h-atom

The q. you found isn't a good dupe - is much more specific.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/15662/why-is-formic-acid-a-stronger-acid-than-acetic-acid

@Scientisτ the article states "To a very large extent, the problem is more pedagogic than practical. In reality, there are probably no directly observable consequences for the revised position" :). Besides we are taught a lot of outdated stuff anyway

The answers here seem to keep repeating the myth that alkyl groups are inductively electron-donating.
Full disclosure. I'm the lead author on this paper, and have spent the last year (with my colleagues) looking into this. PLEASE take the time to read the paper before commenting. It is open access, so anyone can read it.
One commenter mentions the instability of tertiary carbanions. See JACS 1989,page 1968. The t-butyl carbanion is more stable than the methyl carbanion. I know this isn't what it says in your textbooks, but this is the definitive information.
The problem is, you can build a house of cards on alkyl group inductive electron-donating effects. I suggest doing what we did, and look for the original evidence that supports this. Basically, the evidence is very small, and can all be explained in other ways now.
Carbon is more electronegative than hydrogen. All alkyl groups are inductively electron-withdrawing relative to hydrogen.
I'm happy to engage in constructive dialog about this, but please don't dismiss it just because your textbooks say something different. I've spoken to several textbook authors, and none of them (yet!) who have seen our paper disagree with the conclusions.

This is the article mentioned in this answer

If I may ask, what caused you to look into this?

In all honesty, something just didn’t feel right about the ‘old’ position. And when I started digging, I found that others had expressed the same concerns, but no-one had listened. So it became a matter of finding the definitive proof, and disseminating it widely enough to change minds.

Alkyl groups are indeed electron donating groups by two effects:- Inductive effect (+I) and hyperconjugation (H). If it was otherwise, then it won't be able to explain stuff like stability of tertiary carbocation, and hence the rearrangement of carbocations, and also factors like acidity and basicity.
For instance, neobutyl carbocation is stable due to the +I effect of the three  methyl groups attached to the central carbon atom which helps in neutralizing the plus charge on the carbon atom(since carbon is an electronegative atom, it doesn't tolerate positive charge on it). The positive inductive effect of alkyl group is the same reason for the instability of a 3° carbanion.
If we consider 1°,2° and 3° alcohols, 1° is more acidic as the multiple alkyl groups attached to oxygen in tertiary and secondary increase the electron density on the O atom once, hence reducing its tendancy to lose a proton and become oxide ion.

OP's concerns have to do with a paper they have linked. It would be better to go through that, read their arguments (where they attempt to explain precisely the same phenomena), and then make an answer. They mainly address the issues of carbocation and alkoxide stability through the hyperconjugative effect (which is true for carbocations). I'm afraid the answer is not very productive as is.

@Sonder It is true that Carbon being an electronegative atom has a very minute tendency to pull the electron cloud towards itself but it is actually negligible, and the hyperconjugation effect hence dominates in the case of an alkyl group. Hence, the reason for the stability of a tertiary carbocation can be explained by the presence of 9 Alpha hydrogen atoms which stabilizes the cation by hyperconjugation.
